# How to convert nested JSON to csv in C#?

Tags: c#, .net, json, csv

I am trying to use `Newtonsoft.Json` to deserialize below `JSON` to `csv` but failed.  I am unable to properly define the schema of the JSON and thus failed.

Input JSON:

```
{
 "2017-02-11":
  {
  "Table1": [
    {
      "code": "code day1.1.1",
      "no": "no day1.1.1"
    }
  ],
  "Table2": [
    {
      "code": "code day1.2.1",
      "no": "no day1.2.1"
    },
    {
      "code": "code day1.2.2",
      "no": "no day1.2.2"
    }
  ]
 },
 "2017-02-12":
  {
  "Table1": [
    {
      "code": "code day2.1.1",
      "no": "no day2.1.1"
    },
    {
      "code": "code day2.1.2",
      "no": "no day2.1.2"
    }
  ],
  "Table2": [
    {
      "code": "code day2.2.1",
      "no": "no day2.2.1"
    }
  ]
 }
}
```

Output csv:

```
,,code,no
2017-02-11,Table1,code day1.1.1,no day1.1.1
,Table2,code day1.2.1,no day1.2.1
,,code day1.2.2,no day1.2.2
2017-02-12,Table1,code day2.1.1,no day2.1.1
,,code day2.1.2,no day2.1.2
,Table2,code day2.2.1,no day2.2.1
```

When I try to use

```
DataSet dataSet = Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<DataSet>(content).
```

It returns exception.

Comment: You can deserialize that JSON to a `IDictionary<DateTime, DataSet>` just by doing `var dataSets = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<SortedDictionary<DateTime, DataSet>>(content);`.  Sample [fiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/ZIMrU0).  Does that answer your question or are you also asking how to write a CSV file?

Answer (score 0):

When you deserialise an object, your returning type needs properties which match that of the object names in the JSON.

Your JSON uses dates as objects names, which I assume means that these values are dynamic. If they are dynamic, then I'd recommend using

```
var dynamicResults = JSON.Decode(content);
```

Decode returns a dynamic list type which can be looped through, from there you can bind your results from each dynamic into a new DataSet type.